# Knime with database

Tags: sql-server, knime

How to add new driver into database through KNIME preferences? Generally,

```
File-> Preferences -> Add File/ Add Directory
```

The files accepted are only of `*.jar` or `*.zip`.

**MY QUESTION**

I have installed `ODBC64` into my PC. Now I need to add that file into `knime` preferences and use the Driver into Database Connector node.

- How to add and use the file into my Knime?
- And What  is meant by Database URL `jdbc:mysql://host:port/database_name`
  Host and port?

Can anyone please briefly explain and  help me out?

Comment: (I doubt the URL for an MS SQL Server would contain the string `mysql` in the protocol part.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based on your database URL of jdbc:mysql:// that you are wanting to connect to a MySQL database?  Based on that, then there is a thread on the [KNIME forum](https://www.knime.com/forum/knime-developers/connecing-to-mysql-on-a-pc) which explains pretty much all of your question, but the process is the same for any other sort of database.  The steps are as follows:

1. Download the jdbc driver (e.g. from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ for MySQL) - NB KNIME now comes bundled with several drivers already installed - MySQL is one of those - in the Database Connector node the drivers installed are listed.
2. In the database URL, you need to change those parts in `<>` - i.e. the hostname, port number and database name.  Hostname may be localhost if it is a local database.  The port number you will need to find from your database administrator, or will be what you set it up to be if you are running a local database (3306 is the default for MySQL), so for a database called 'myDB' on the default port on your local machine, the url should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB`

For some of the shipped drivers, there are also connector nodes, e.g. MySQL Connector, SQLite Connector, PostgreSQL Connector etc, which still require the server name/port and database name, but take them as individual inputs rather than requiring editing of the URL

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of KNIME are based on Java 8, which [dropped support for ODBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999476), so you should first find an alternative driver for your database and only after you can connect to that with KNIME as described on the [KNIME documentation page for DB connectors](https://www.knime.com/database-documentation).

Comment: Thank you @SteveR. But found that, as KNIME was built with Eclipse which is java based mostly the drivers are supported by only JDBC. Is it true?

Comment: @UmaRamya I think only jdbc, yes

Comment: @SteveR Thankyou! :)

Comment: @Gabor Bakos Does nodes in knime support for auto update (get the updated data from database for every 5 hours) ? Is any nodes are available in knime?

Answer (score 0):

You have several nodes which allow you to connect to a DB (especially MySQL). 
I remember there was a dedicated MySQL node for connecting with the DB.
Just remember this: you have to input the IP adress : port, then insert credentials and point to the DB you want to open by default.